# Chrome blocks file with correct CORS header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using express to make an app which you could POST to and it would send to a private discord channel. However, when I tried to POST to it in a web app in Chrome, it says that no Access Allow Control Origin header is present on the file.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://lightcraftsapithing.herokuapp.com/api/discord/contact' from origin
'https://lightcraftmc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

However, when I try to do the exact same thing on Postman, the response does have the header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This is my script for the website:

```js
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url:'https://lightcraftsapithing.herokuapp.com/api/discord/contact', 
            data:{
                "name": document.getElementById('name').value,
                "email": document.getElementById('email').value,
                "subject": document.getElementById('subject').value,
                "message": document.getElementById('name').value
                },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }})
    }
```

I feel like something is wrong with the jquery script. How can I solve it?

Edit: server side script:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
res.status(200).send(data)
```

Comment: There is an express middleware called [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) which can help you in these scenarios

Comment: CORS is something that needs to be enabled or allowed on the server you are doing the request to

Comment: Please post the *complete* server side script. Do you also put this header on responses to OPTIONS requests?

Comment: I did the exact same thing for a GET endpoint and that worked. I will try the cors middleware and OPTIONS requests, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide this configuration on the server-side
Ex. for express:

```
const express=require('express');
const app= express();
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```